# Pointing the main field in package.json conditionally

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a Monorepo under Lerna and Yarn Workspaces. The repo has packages which are published to npm and consumed outside the monorepo as well as within the monorepo. While developing in the monorepo we would like the `main` field of `package.json` for all such packages to point to the `src` directory, while when a package is used outside the monorepo, we would like the consumer to use the transpiled code in the `dist` folder.

I want this to be consistent across all uses of the packages, My current solution is to have the `main` field point to the `dist` folder. Then for each of the tools within the monorepo, namely `jest`, `tsc`, `webpack`, `parcel` I've had to come up with a different tool specific solution for aliasing the `src` directory instead of the `dist` directory. But I don't like the fact that I've had to do this work for each of these tools. It just doesn't seem scalable.

Has anybody come up with a lower level solution, where a module resolves to a different folder based on the environment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your internal code base is always transpiling the sources, why not just `import { thing } from "my-package/src/main.js`?

Then you can just leave the main field as dist for the consumers who ideally shouldn't have to keep track of additional paths when importing your packages.

There are a lot of details left our in your answer, but assuming you're using a single webpack/other instance to compile all your packages.

Another approach, since you're already coupled all your packages via the same compilation step, why not just use relative paths between the packages? That way you'll never have to act as a consumer but with slightly different needs.

And finally the third approach, which I think sounds a bit convoluted but should do exactly what you're asking for. Create a script that uses globby or some other npm package to grab all package.json files in your repository (excluding node_modules!). require() / iterate through these package.json manifest files and set the main field to an input value (say "dist"). Then, create two bin js files (hint: bin field) called set-main-dist and set-main-src, and possibly a third called unset-main.

Next, no matter what scripts you run in your package.json files at the root (or using lerna run), make sure to let the script look either like this:

`"prebuild": "set-main-src"`

or like this

`"build": "set-main-src && build etc"`

Hope one of these options work out for you. Remember that it's rarely worth going against the stream of usual patterns in tooling and what not. Make this one worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same dilemma but with yarn3.

The solution importing always from source dint worked for my case, as the package itself might get published to npm too.

So after digging around I luckily found the package.json property `publishConfig.main` https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#publishConfig

With it I can change the main field from source to dist on npm publish.
Basically only for publishing we use a modified package.json.

Implemented in my package.json it looks like this:

```json
{
   "main": "./src/index.ts",
   "publishConfig": {
     "main": "./dist/index.js"
   }
}
```

and when I run `yarn npm publish` or `yarn pack` the `main` field will be replaced temporary for the zip.
While all my tooling (jest and ts) can still rely on the `main` field pointing to the source.